# delay JQuery effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I want to fade out an element and all its child elements after a delay of a few seconds. but I haven't found a way to specify that an effect should start after a specified time delay.

Comment: Can you give an example of when the children of an element aren't faded with the element?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'll update the post

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#foo').fadeOut(); }, 5000);
```

The 5000 is five seconds in milliseconds.

Comment: Note that this is using Javascript's built-in setTimeout function, nothing jQuery specific.

Comment: This only partially answers his question, I think.

Answer (score 43):

I use this pause plugin I just wrote

```
$.fn.pause = function(duration) {
    $(this).animate({ dummy: 1 }, duration);
    return this;
};
```

Call it like this :

```
$("#mainImage").pause(5000).fadeOut();
```

Note: you don't need a callback.

---

**Edit: You should now use the [jQuery 1.4. built in delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method. I haven't checked but I assume its more 'clever' than my plugin.**

Comment: just watch out if jQuery ever adds a pause() function because there's will probably be better than mine! but its good to abstract away what youre doing like this

Comment: can someone explain WHY i dont need a callback? i'm not quite sure why this doesnt return immediately

Comment: jQuery has a built in animation queue... if you never reset/stop the queue, the "pause" acts as period of animation that doesn't actually animate anything.

Comment: stop() doesn't work with delay(), so I still use your dummy animation hack. (bug http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6576 )

Answer (score 19):

Previously you would do something like this

```
$('#foo').animate({opacity: 1},1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

The first animate isn't doing anything since you already have opacity 1 on the element, but it would pause for the amount of time.

In jQuery 1.4, they have built this into the framework so you don't have to use the hack like above.

```
$('#foo').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

The functionality is the same as the original `jQuery.delay()` plugin http://www.evanbot.com/article/jquery-delay-plugin/4

Answer (score 11):

The best way is by using the jQuery delay method:

$('#my_id').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using setTimeout by using the fadeTo() method, and setting a 5 second delay on that.

```
$("#hideAfterFiveSeconds").click(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo(5000,1,function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: doing this kind of block is very cpu intensive compared to setTimeout. I don't see the advantage. - Why is avoiding the native timer necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a plugin to let you add a delay into the chain.

for example $('#div').fadeOut().delay(5000).fadeIn(); // fade element out, wait 5 seconds, fade element back in.

It doesn't use any animation hacks or excessive callback chaining, just simple clean short code.

http://blindsignals.com/index.php/2009/07/jquery-delay/