# jQuery how to reinitialize a delay function

Tags: jquery

I am using a Jquery time delayed fader like below, but need to reinitialize it based upon events in the code, ie knock the timer back to zero. How do I do this? I've tried just calling fader() again.

```
function fader(){ 

$(ajdiv).delay(10000, function(){$(ajdiv).fadeOut()});

}
jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){ //run a delayed function

return this.each(function(){

    setTimeout(func,time);

});

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the timeoutID returned from setTimeout. You can call window.clearTimeout(timeoutID) to remove the timer and stop the event from happening. You'd have to create a new one afterwards in case of "resetting".

The mozilla [documentation for setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects) too, it's got a (in my opinion) more elegant solution to I think the same problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks! :D Do you know if this works for other browsers also?

Comment: Yes, it's supported by all mayor browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is my actual code that I used (it makes a new element slide from left stay for time given to my custom delay function and then disappear again):

```
$element.next().next().hide().show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 700, function () {$(this).delay(10000, function() {$element.next().next().hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 700)})});
```