# How to make a jQuery step animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I have searched for anything on how to animate a color wheel using jquery to step through the defined colors in order and I can't seem to find anything.

What I'm looking to do is spiral an effect by "opening" slivers of the colors at 45 degrees and open them in order like a spiral and then close them in order. Starting from blank and ending with blank. By open I mean some kind of slide effect (hard to think of the correct term) but think of a loading gif spiral that looks like it's spiraling. (Like the mac rainbow wheel, only making the previous colors disappear after cycling through.)

I'm using jquery and would prefer a jquery solution so I don't have to worry about browser compatibility issues, but I could accept css transitions as a last resort.

I've attached some images to give a better visual idea. I have no code right now but my plan was just to have a div inside the body where the jquery would draw or do this animation. I really don't even know where to start so I don't have anything to build from nor do I really know the exact terminology I'm looking for. Hopefully my images will give a better understanding. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the top image...the start should be blank just like the finished.

Comment: How about creating a gif out of those images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628576/jquery-gif-animations

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Do you some code we can use a starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [moredemons's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16488235/227299) answer as a basis, [using CSS triangles](http://www.uselesspickles.com/triangles/). It does the same thing, but it properly separates the CSS so you don't have to edit the JS to edit the colors. The JS is also simpler, doesn't rely on `if/elses` for all 16 states.

The main benefit of a programatic solution over a gif is that you can customize the colors, sizes, animation rate more easily.

- [Small, green, blue, fast](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYKmQ/10)
- [Big, red, blue, slow](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYKmQ/8/)
- [Big with a different arrangement](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYKmQ/6/)

**Initial HTML** All triangles hidden

```
<div id ="ct" >
    <div class="triangle triangle-nw triangle-hide-tr triangle-hide-bl"></div>
    <div class="triangle triangle-ne triangle-hide-tl triangle-hide-br"></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="triangle triangle-sw triangle-hide-tl triangle-hide-br"></div>
    <div class="triangle triangle-se triangle-hide-tr triangle-hide-bl" ></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    font-size:0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;    
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.triangle-se {
    border-color: red red blue blue;
}

.triangle-sw {
    border-color: red blue blue red;
}

.triangle-nw {
    border-color: blue blue red red;
}

.triangle-ne {
    border-color: blue red red blue;
}

.triangle-hide-tl {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.triangle-hide-tr {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;    
}

.triangle-hide-br {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;        
}

.triangle-hide-bl {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;        
}
```

**JS**

```
setInterval((function(){
    var index = 0;
    // Which square is going to be modified in each stage (16 stages)
    var map = [3,3,2,2,0,0,1,1,3,3,2,2,0,0,1,1];
    // The clases to add and remove
    var classesToChange = ['tr', 'bl', 'br', 'tl', 'bl', 'tr', 'tl', 'br'];           
    return function() {
        var el = $('#ct div.triangle').eq(map[index]);
        if (index < 8) {
            // Showing pieces
            el.removeClass('triangle-hide-' + classesToChange[index] );
        } else {
            // Hiding pieces
            el.addClass('triangle-hide-' + classesToChange[index - 8] );
        }
        index++;
        if (index >= 16) {
            index = 0;
        }
    };
})(), 200);
```

Comment: I think this is probably going to be the most complete solution. I'll do some testing and see if I can't break it but so far it looks pretty great. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know my solution is weird a lot, but there's no another solution as I see. I used `border`s to create 45° corners and jQuery `animate` with `step` on fake element.

So, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WYKmQ/1/

Comment: I don't think it's weird, it's really nice. It'd be better if you could change the colors with CSS

Comment: I added an answer based on yours, you can modify the colors in CSS now, check it out

Comment: I also don't think that's weird. I initially was thinking about borders because I do some similar things, but I didn't think I could with as many sections. Thanks for showing me that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply looking for an animated gif.
Why overcomplicate things with javascript when it's not needed.
A gif will show perfectly in any browser.

Here, it took me 3 minutes to do this. Less time than any code.

[image]

Comment: There is no code... it's an animated gif... the whole point of doing it with an image instead of code... In other words: it took me 3 minutes to create this animated gif which is less time than if I tried to code it.

Comment: The point of writing code is that you can parameterize it and give it new dimensions and colors, not go back to a drawing program. Not downvoting, but I think this misunderstands the question

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree but from what I understood from the question and other answers, it will most likely just change background-position  of an image so instead of doing that, might as well use the animated gif.

Comment: My answer provides a programmatic solution. Easy to modify everything now, the size, the delay, the colors. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYKmQ/3/, http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYKmQ/5/

Comment: Yeah I know I could have made a gif but I wanted it for different sections, colors, sizes, etc. I could make a bunch of them but if I want to change them later than I'd be back to the "drawing" board. (Pardon my pun...)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** your example >> [**mi-creativity.com/test/color-wheel**](http://mi-creativity.com/test/fading-sprite-background/cc.html)

You can achieve the same above effect by using what so called image-sprites, you include all of them in one image, queuing them vertically or horizontally and changing the background-position just like in this example (you can view the page source to know how to do it)

[mi-creativity.com/test/fading-sprite-background](http://mi-creativity.com/test/fading-sprite-background/aa.html)

The above example uses a jquery plugin called `jquery.bgpos.js` as will as a .png image

---

Another way of doing it you can set each of above images as a back-ground image each for a different class wit ha numerical value and you change the div class by making use of `toggleClass` jquery property like in this example - *check the page source* -:

[mi-creativity.com/test/fading-sprite-background](http://mi-creativity.com/test/fading-sprite-background/bb.html)

Which I prefer because it is easier to modify it and add more frames if you want.

P.S: you don;t need another blank frame at the beginning, just move the last frame to the beginning, because if you used two blank frames that would affect the smoothness of the motion