# How do I delay an animation (in jquery)

Tags: jquery

How can I trigger a slideUp(); with a delayed start, but which doesn't force the rest of the code to wait until it has finished before progressing.

eg: A button is pressed and 1 second later a box disappears, but jquery is still working during that one second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delay JQuery effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects) on exactly the same topic.

```
setTimeout(function() { /* code to run */ }, delay_time_in_milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript's [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function for this.

E.g.

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#someid').slideUp(); }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1sec.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) method to queue animations.

```
$('#el').delay(1000).slideUp();
```

If you want to delay something else, then use JavaScript's built-in [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // code to be executed
}, 1000);
```

Note that you need to specify the delay in milliseconds in both cases. 1000 ms = 1 s.