# Jquery Script pauses

Tags: jquery

Can anyone recommend the best way to pause a script until a second after page load?

Thanks
paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. setTimeout JS plain-and-simple JS standard.
2. delay(n) jQuery method.

Both are explained here [delay JQuery effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects)

Answer (score 0):

I answered this a couple of days ago:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        ...  // put your body here
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By enclosing your script inside the following jQuery code, execution will be delayed until after everything in your page has loaded:

```
$(function() {
  // your code goes here...
});
```