# Jquery delay() function

Tags: jquery, delay

I have some jquery and am trying to apply a delay to it but can't seem to get it to work.

The current jquery is as follows...

```
image.css({"visibility" : "hidden"}).removeClass("image-background");
```

and I have tried ammending this according to the jquery website (http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to apply the delay...

```
image.delay(800).css({"visibility" : "hidden"}).removeClass("image-background");
```

but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Can anyone see a problem with this? Or how I could fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `delay()` function only applies to actions queued on the element. Most commonly, but not always, these are actions created by the `animate()` method. In this case, use `setTimeout` to run some code after a specified interval.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    image.css({"visibility" : "hidden"}).removeClass("image-background");
}, 800);
```

Comment: ahhhh ok, thanks very much for the help and the quick response

Comment: It isn't correct to say that `.delay()` only applies to animation.

Answer (score 35):

`.delay()` is not only for animations.

It's for anything in a `queue`.

```
image.delay(800)
     .queue(function( nxt ) {
         $(this).css({"visibility":"hidden"}).removeClass("image-background");
         nxt(); // continue the queue
     });
```

*For the down voter:*

## [HERE'S A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgssA/)

Comment: Oh, the uninformed down voters strike again. This answer is absolutely correct, and doesn't give wrong information like the others. I guess on StackOverflow that means it should be down voted.

Comment: Thank you for not only saying what `delay()` does, but for showing `queue()` as well.