# Why doesn't this simple toggle work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok firstly - its not a `toggle()` as such.

This code is supposed to work like a slider. 1 Div is showing, you click a button, and the next div shows, click another button, and the first div shows.

This works so far, but it doesn't work going backwards. So the button works to show the 2nd Div, but hitting the 'less' button I made just makes the second div disappear and the 1st remains hidden.

Here is the code:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('.c1')
        .animate({ left: "-828px" }, 600, 'easeInOutQuint')
        .delay(300, function() {
            $('.c2').animate({ left: "0px" }, 600, 'easeInOutQuint'); 
        }
    );
});

$('.less').click(function() {
    $('.c2')
        .animate({ left: "828px" }, 600, 'easeInOutQuint')
        .delay(300, function(){
            $('.c1').animate({ left: "0px" }, 600, 'easeInOutQuint'); 
        }
    );
});
```

What am I missing? And how could I do this so that I'm basically not repeating the same code twice?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Diego - good idea http://jsfiddle.net/jDFxN/

Comment: You made your example wrong. Here it is behaving as you say in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/jDFxN/1/

Comment: @Diego oops - quite right you are! thanks!

Comment: So any ideas why the .less click function isn't working?

Comment: I've been looking it for a while.. but I can't find out anything :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong concept about `.delay`.

In jquery documentation:

> Description: Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

And its parameters are: `duration [, queueName]`.

Also, from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8401335/310276):

> The delay() function only applies to actions queued on the element

So I think your best choice is, as @nicolast said, use the callbacks. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDFxN/3/) it is working. And the final code is:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('.c1')
        .animate({ left: "-400px" }, 600, function() {
            $('.c2').animate({ left: "0px" }, 600);
        }
    );
});

$('.less').click(function() {
    $('.c2')
        .animate({ left: "400px" }, 600, function(){
            $('.c1').animate({ left: "0px" }, 600);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried with callback functions instead of delay ?

```
$('.more').click(function(){
    $('.c1').animate({ left:"-828px"}, 600, 'easeInOutQuint',function(){
       $('.c2').animate({left:"0px"}, 600, 'easeInOutQuint'); 
    });
});
$('.less').click(function(){
    $('.c2').animate({ left:"828px"}, 600, 'easeInOutQuint',function(){
       $('.c1').animate({left:"0px"}, 600, 'easeInOutQuint'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: It definitely had a different outcome doing what you suggested - but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This reproduce works.
When pressing more: c1 goes to -100px and after that c2 goes to 0px
When pressing less: c2 goes to 100px and after that c1 goes to 0px

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('.c1')
    .stop()
    .animate({ left: "-100px" }, 600, 'linear')
    .delay(300, function() {
        $('.c2').stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, 600, 'linear'); 
    });
});

$('.less').click(function() {
    $('.c2')
    .stop()
    .animate({ left: "100px" }, 600, 'linear')
    .delay(300, function(){
        $('.c1').stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, 600, 'linear'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately, for me. The animation has definitely stopped anyways so I don't see how that would fix it unless I was trying to click back and forth really quickly (which I'm not) - either way, +1 because I should probably be putting in a stop() anyways - but the second button isn't visible until the animation is complete.

Comment: I edited my answer and put my own reproduce there. C1 and C2 have position: relative.