# add a delay to javascript fadeIn effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delay JQuery effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251204/delay-jquery-effects)

Does anyone know how I can add a time delay of about 1 second to this script?

I want the `modcontentplatinummore` div that fadesIn to fade in about a second after `modcontentplatinum` fades out.

Thanks.

```
<script>
$(".modcontentplatinummore").hide();
$('.morebutton-platinum').click(function () {
    if ($('.modcontentplatinummore').is(":hidden")) {       
        $('.modcontentplatinum').fadeOut(500);
        $('.modcontentplatinummore').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('.modcontentplatinummore').fadeOut(500);
        $('.modcontentplatinum').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Diodeus: +1, although that question favours an answer for outdated jQuery versions (pre-1.4) :-/

Comment: zzz Have you ever even looked at the jQuery documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`delay` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) which adds a timeout to the animation queue.

Answer (score 0):

We can add delay using the delay() in jquery please use this link http://api.jquery.com/delay/